# Can't get my Docker Desktop c# web api environment running with docker-compose

Tags: c#, docker, kubernetes, docker-compose, asp.net-core-webapi

I'm experimenting with Docker to get more familiar with the technology, and plan on experimenting with Kubernetes as well.

For my experiment, I made a .NET 6 web api project that creates a container app named "Holovacs.Kubernetes.Authentication.WebApi". It's literally a cookie-cutter sample web api project. I checked the box to create it as a container and this makes a Dockerfile:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:6.0 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0 AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["Holovacs.Kubernetes.Authentication.WebApi/Holovacs.Kubernetes.Authentication.WebApi.csproj", "Holovacs.Kubernetes.Authentication.WebApi/"]
RUN dotnet restore "Holovacs.Kubernetes.Authentication.WebApi/Holovacs.Kubernetes.Authentication.WebApi.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/Holovacs.Kubernetes.Authentication.WebApi"
RUN dotnet build "Holovacs.Kubernetes.Authentication.WebApi.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "Holovacs.Kubernetes.Authentication.WebApi.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish /p:UseAppHost=false

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "Holovacs.Kubernetes.Authentication.WebApi.dll"]
```

I can run this thing in debug mode on Docker Desktop: [image: Container Running in Docker Desktop]

...and, hey! The Swagger page comes up, letting me know it's running as expected:
[image]

So next I build out my "development environment" using docker-compose. My `docker-compose.yml` file:

```
version: '3'
name: devenv
services:
  authdbserver:
    image: postgres:latest
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 35432:5432
    environment:
      POSTGRES_DB: authdb
      POSTGRES_USER: authsvcuser
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: X1Mz9YdFol0pw!t
  appdbserver:
    image: postgres:latest
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 35433:5432
    environment:
      POSTGRES_DB: appdb
      POSTGRES_USER: appsvcuser
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: vgm3UsjF0UYxaI
  dbadmin:
    image: dpage/pgadmin4:latest
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 30080:80
    links:
      - authdbserver
      - appdbserver
    environment:
      PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL: admin@admin.com
      PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD: secret
      PGADMIN_LISTEN_PORT: 80
  auditdb:
    image: mongo:latest
    restart: always
    ports: 
     - 37017:27017
    environment:
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME: admin
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD: secret
  mongoadmin:
    image: mongo-express:latest
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 38081:8081
    environment:
      ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINUSERNAME: admin
      ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINPASSWORD: secret
      ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_URL: mongodb://admin:secret@auditdb:27017/   
  hkauthsvc:
    image: holovacskubernetesauthenticationwebapi:dev
    restart: always
    ports: 
      - 30081:80
    links:
      - authdbserver
      - appdbserver
      - auditdb
    environment:
      AUTH_SVC_CONN: Server=authdbserver;Database=authdb;User Id=authsvcuser;Password=eX1Mz9YdFol0pw!t;
      APP_SVC_CONN: Server=appdbserver;Database=appdb;User Id=appsvcuser;Password=vgm3UsjF0UYxaI;
  rabbitmq:
    image: rabbitmq:management
    ports: 
     - 35672:15672
    environment:
      RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_USER: admin@admin.com
      RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_PASS: secret
```

...on the command line, I navigate to the folder I created this yml file in and run it:

```
docker-compose up
[+] Running 7/0
 ✔ Container devenv-appdbserver-1   Created                                                                        0.0s
 ✔ Container devenv-auditdb-1       Created                                                                        0.0s
 ✔ Container devenv-rabbitmq-1      Created                                                                        0.0s
 ✔ Container devenv-mongoadmin-1    Created                                                                        0.0s
 ✔ Container devenv-authdbserver-1  Created                                                                        0.0s
 ✔ Container devenv-dbadmin-1       Created                                                                        0.0s
 ✔ Container devenv-hkauthsvc-1     Created                                                                        0.0s

(lots of startup logs)

devenv-hkauthsvc-1 exited with code 0
devenv-hkauthsvc-1 exited with code 0
devenv-hkauthsvc-1 exited with code 0
devenv-hkauthsvc-1 exited with code 0 (this keeps repeating...)
```

Note the `devenv-hkauthsvc-1` container keeps exiting. I can't keep it running, and it won't respond on port 30081. There are no associated logs with this. There don't appear to be any errors. It just runs, stops, and runs again.

I've seen some SO articles suggesting that I need to be listening to STDIN or set this interactive somehow... do I? That seems to be an odd limitation that I haven't had to do with literally any of these other containers. Have I misconfigured something? Is this a quirk of c#/ web-api, asp.net, microsoft? Am I doing something wrong, or making some incorrect assumptions? Please advise.

NOTE: for giggles, I tried to run this in Visual Studio in Release configuration, and changed my image to `holovacskubernetesauthenticationwebapi:latest` (not sure where the dev and latest tags are coming from) and used `docker-compose up -d` and now when I run the container, it doesn't seem to stop... there's even some logs for the .net container... but it's still not responding.

Comment: Logs should be visible via `docker logs devenv-hkauthsvc-1`. Hopefully that'll give some insight.

Comment: There's literally nothing there. No logs at all.

Comment: How do you produce the `holovacskubernetesauthenticationwebapi` image? If you do `docker run -i holovacskubernetesauthenticationwebapi ...` do you see any useful output?

Comment: I honestly don't know how it's happening. Visual Studio seems to wrap most of the guts in UI... which is generally very nice, but not so much in troubleshooting. Running that command gets it to start, but it doesn't seem to be listening to anything.

Comment: People love to downvote. Anyone care to explain why they think it's a bad question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All right I figured this out. The dev version of the image does not play nice with the docker compose, I'm assuming because it's expecting a debugger to be attached to it. When I built the image as a release configuration, it no longer immediately exited... but calls to the endpoint were coming up blank. I thought something else was wrong, but it was actually fine; in Release config, the redirect to swagger (indeed, the entire swagger UI) is disabled by default. So it was actually working fine at that point, I just needed to hit a real endpoint. After all the headache I'd had with the other parts, I just assumed I'd screwed something else up.